# Is there a field extension $E$ containing $S$ which has finite dimension when considered as a vector space over $S?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, extension-field

An algebraic number field (or simply number field) is an extension field
$K$
of the field of rational numbers
$\mathbb {Q}$  such that the field extension
$K/\Bbb Q$ has finite degree (and hence is an algebraic field extension). Thus
$K$ is a field that contains
$\mathbb {Q}$  and has finite dimension when considered as a vector space over
$\mathbb {Q}.$

Consider:

$$ \exp: \Bbb Q \to (S \subset \Bbb R^+) $$

$(S,\times)$ is a group. Furthermore $(S,\times, *)$ is a field by:

$$ m: S \times S \to S $$
with $(e^a,e^b)$ to $e^{ab},$ where $a,b \in \Bbb Q.$

> Is there a field extension $E$ containing $S$ which has finite dimension when considered as a vector space over $S?$

Comment: Note that given the field structure you defined on $S$, the map $\exp$ becomes a field isomorphism $\mathbb{Q} \cong S$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch yes - wondering what a non-trivial extension of $S$ might be. Any idea?

Comment: and why can/can't we extend $S$ to something isomorphic to the p-adic number system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such an extension exists. One possibility is to take any extension field $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, given you have one at hand: $K$ is, up to isomorphism, a field extension of $S$, because $S$ is, up to isomorphism, just $\mathbb{Q}$.

An easy possibility, if I understand your question correctly, would be $E = S$. This is trivially a field extension of $S$ of dimension $1$. Please give me a hint if I didn't understand your question correctly.

Comment: You have not defined $K$.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: The answer is absolutely fine as it is. Working code or documentation citations are not required.

Comment: +1 nerdontour you understood my question. if you have a non-trivial extension let me know :)

Comment: @geocalc33 We know non-trivial extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, right? For instance, $K = \mathbb{Q} + i\mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q}[i]$ (the rational complex numbers) is an algebraic field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. So by the field isomorphism $\exp^{-1}$, it is isomorphic to a field extension of $S$.
However, I cannot (at least not right away) come up with a non-trivial field extension that is explicit, i. e. that is not given by the isomorphism $\mathbb{Q} \simeq S$.

Comment: okay ill ask about this in a new question